# Batch Trim Lines in Text File after Sub-String - REM Trim with Expansion

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, for-loop, trim

I am running Windows 10 Pro using batch files (open to using VBS and PS1 files) and I have a text file automatically exported by software that can look like this:

```
Sub_Group691_FE7IP11_2017-12-12.sldasm_bin/parts/Loft-Project.sldasm_bin/parts/Loft-Project...
Sub_Group691_FE7IP12_2017-12-12.sldasm_bin/parts/Loft-Project.sldasm_bin/parts/Loft-Project...
Sub_Group691_FE7IP13_2017-12-12.sldasm_bin/parts/Loft-Project.sldasm_bin/parts/Loft-Project...
```

Each line continues specifying sub-parts after the "..." and could contain "poison" characters. The Sub_Group part is pulled from the filename and can also contain "poison" characters.

What I am looking to do is export just the filename which is right at the beginning of each line, up to and including the first file extension, in this case ".sldasm." Everything to the right of the first instance of .sldasm should be trimmed.

What I have cobbled together so far from research on Stackoverflow is:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "inputfile=C:\Scratch\ASMExport.txt"
SET "outputfile=C:\Scratch\InputFiles.txt"
(
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%inputfile%") DO (
  SET "currentline=%%a"
  ECHO("!currentline:.sldasm=.sldasm & rem "!"
 )
)>"%outputfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

My problem lies with the "rem" line, which does not seem to work as intended either because of being within a FOR loop or because of needing to enable delayed expansion. It seems to be parsing the "& rem" as text, which looks to be because of the way delayed expansion works. What I get from the above lines is:

```
SubGroup691_FE7IP11_2017-12-12.sldasm" & rem "/bin/parts/Loft-Project.sldasm" & rem ""
SubGroup691_FE7IP12_2017-12-12.sldasm" & rem "/bin/parts/Loft-Project.sldasm" & rem ""
SubGroup691_FE7IP13_2017-12-12.sldasm" & rem "/bin/parts/Loft-Project.sldasm" & rem ""
```

I can use this same line outside the loop and without ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "inputstring=Sub_Group691_FE7IP11_2017-12-12.sldasm_bin/parts/Loft-Project.sldasm_bin/parts/Loft-Project"
SET "outputstring=%inputstring:.sldasm=.sldasm & rem "%"
echo %outputstring%
```

The output to that would give me what I am looking for:

```
Sub_Group691_FE7IP11_2017-12-12.sldasm
```

In searching, I am beginning to think that rem cannot be used in this way, and I must move to a token delimiter loop using a bogus delimiter.

I would be content in getting this to work and not worrying about "poison" characters in the filename by being diligent about naming files correctly.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `& rem` approach to truncate strings to the right cannot work with [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (`!`), it relies on normal/immediate expansion (`%`). This is because immediate expansion is done before commands (like `rem`) are recognised, but delayed expansion happens afterwards, so the `rem` command is never executed.

However, you could in the loop [replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) every `.sldasm` by a forbidden character like `|` and then split the string by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), like this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "InputFile=C:\Scratch\ASMExport.txt"
set "OutputFile=C:\Scratch\InputFiles.txt"
set "Extension=.sdlasm"

> "%OutputFile%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
        set "CurrentLine=%%A"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "CurrentLine=!CurrentLine:%Extension%=|!"
        for /F "delims=|" %%B in ("!CurrentLine!") do (
            endlocal
            echo(%%B
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Delayed expansion is toggled so that no `for` variables become expanded when it is enabled, in order to avoid loss of or problems with exclamation marks.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on delayed expansion, it was really helpful! Your example is exactly what I was looking for, and introduced a new concept to me (replacing the search string with a forbidden character). That is thinking outside the box. You guys (and gals) are amazing! Thank you again, aschipfl!

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q47788829.txt"

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1delims=/" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%d IN ("%%c") DO (
ECHO %%%%-a=%%~a %%%%-b=%%~b %%%%-c=%%~c %%%%-d=%%~d %%%%-e=%%~e ^<^<
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.
I used a file named `q47788829.txt` containing your data for my testing.

You should be able to assemble your required report data from the elements `%%a`..`%%e` displayed. All a matter of using `tokens` and `delims` constructively.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you Magoo! This is neat, re-assembling it from parts. I will pull it apart and study it at each step.

Answer (score -1):

If your input is the text that you wrote, with the same structure, I think this batch should work and extract the names that you want quickly.

**CODE**:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "inputFile=input.txt"
set "outputFile=result.txt"

for /f "delims=/ tokens=1" %%A in (%inputFile%) do (
    set "tempFileName=%%A"
    echo !tempFileName:~0,-4!>> %outputFile%
)
```

You only had to adjust the variables 'inputFile' and 'outputFile' to your needs.